# Pyspark installation is not supported in Jupyter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

Please find my config below:-

I'm using the latest Anaconda for Python + Jupyter:

```
Python version: 3.8.8
Spark version : spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7
Java version: java 16.0.2 2021-07-20

Config:
HADOOP_HOME:D:\spark\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON:jupyter
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS:notebook
SPARK_HOME:D:\spark\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7
path:D:\spark\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7
path:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin

Installed findspark and pyspark from the Anaconda 
pip install findspark 
pip install pyspark
```

Been sitting the whole day and couldn't get this installed in jupyter.

Error

```
<ipython-input-1-84edcc0ab449> in <module>
      1 import findspark
----> 2 findspark.init()
      3 
      4 import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
      5 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    127 
    128     if not spark_home:
--> 129         spark_home = find()
    130 
    131     if not python_path:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\findspark.py in find()
     33 
     34     if not spark_home:
---> 35         raise ValueError(
     36             "Couldn't find Spark, make sure SPARK_HOME env is set"
     37             " or Spark is in an expected location (e.g. from homebrew installation)."

ValueError: Couldn't find Spark, make sure SPARK_HOME env is set or Spark is in an expected location (e.g. from homebrew installation).
```

Comment: Last I checked, Java 16 is not supported by Spark or Hadoop

Comment: so I go with Java 15 . Is that better.

Comment: java 15 also didnt work

Comment: I think i have tried all the possible combinations  but still it didnt work out . tried with Python 3.7 + Spark 2.7 . still jupyter is not gettting the spark home

Comment: You need Java 8 with Spark 2.x. And read the findspark documentation for giving a manual path when the automatic way doesn't work

Comment: ValueError: Couldn't find Spark, make sure SPARK_HOME env is set or Spark is in an expected location (e.g. from homebrew installation).

Comment: Still i couldn't install this for more than a week. Now I'm on Java 8 , Python 3.8.5 , spark 3.1.1.2.7

Comment: Did you read the findspark documentation on how to give a manual location for the Spark home rather than depend on the env var? Otherwise, `print(os.environ.items())` and edit your question to include the output

Comment: the difference is i have to pass the spark_home in the system variable instead of the user env variable. Hence it is not getting deducted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. User and system environment variables are generally the same. Look at the documentation for the init method that accepts a string and use that instead https://github.com/minrk/findspark#find-spark

Comment: I'm using the domain system , company provided laptop . hence it is local system name is different than the domain name .

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't sound like it affects how you can manually edit the parameters passed in the code